# How to use entry widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program in Tkinter that requires the entry widget to be used.  I have looked at different websites, but none of them have CLEARLY expalined how to use the Entry widget and its functions.  Will someone please explain it or give me a great link?

Help would be appreciated on how to get information from the widget.

Comment: It would increase your chances of getting help if you show what you tried and what the problem was.

Comment: I basically want to know the functions of the entry widget and how to use them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a very general question, but [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)'s a website that has great detail, and here's a very simple general example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class application:
    def __init__(self,window):
        """ Initalize the Application """
        self.myentrybox = tk.Entry(window)
        self.myentrybox.pack()
        self.myentrybox.insert(0,"some default value")
        self.myentrybox.bind("<Return>",self.Enter)

    def Enter(self,event):
        """ Someone Pressed Enter """
        print "You entered >> %s" % (self.myentrybox.get())

root=tk.Tk()
myapp = application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Hopefully you can extrapolate what you specifically need to know...

Comment: In python, it's generally agreed that you shouldn't "import *" because you can have name clashes. I think your example would be better if you did something like `import Tkinter as tk` and then prefixed all the tk commands with `tk.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

a = Entry(root)
a.insert(0,"Enter a Text")
a.pack()

def game():
    print(a.get())

enter = Button(root,text="Enter",command=game)
enter.pack()
enter.bind("<Return>",game)



root.mainloop()
```

I think it is the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks @HamzaAmjad..This was very much helpful